# Is it possible to send TCP packet to a device on different network without IP alias

Tags: c, network-programming

I have a C program which is running in a machine A with IP address 192.168.1.10 range and wants to send a TCP packet to a device with IP 172.16.10.5.

Till now I was using the following logic.

set IP alias 172.16.10.100 for machine A using ifconfig command
Open the socket to 172.16.10.5
Send the packet
Close socket
Remove IP alias

Above approach shows side affect like connection drop for existing connections in some cases. Is it possible to send the packet without setting IP alias?

Comment: Doesn't computer A have a route set up (through its default gateway) to the remote machine? If you just plain `ping` the remote IP address (without any "alias" or anything) what happens then?

Comment: Both of the hosts are on the same layer 2 (ethernet) network and you do not have a router?

Comment: Also, adding an IP address of the remote network on your local machine won't do anything useful unless you're actually connected to that same network (in which case you would already have an address in that network). Actually, faking an address of another unconnected network *will* lead to problems, as the remote network won't be able to route packets to your system.

Comment: Some programmer dude, I tried adding ip route(ip route add 172.16.10.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0) and could not connect. My gateway is 192.168.1.1. When using IP alias I can ping and connect remote device. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: IP alias is a bad idea and doesn't make sense on your local network. Your gateway should be able to route this, as with any destinations outside your local network. Is this device on your local network, but has this fixed IP? Can you even ping the device?

Comment: Alexandre, Yes, both devices are on layer 2 switches which are then connected to same router